# jQuery fadeIn/fadeOut between (a & a:hover) in a navigation menu?

Tags: jquery, fadein, transition, fadeout, jquery-hover

i'm trying to do a fadeIn/fadeOut transition between (a and a:hover) on a navigation menu

the nav menu is structured like this:

```
<div class="menubar">
  <ul id="mainmenu">
    <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="">EVENTS</a></li>
    <li><a href="">MultiMedia</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Fans</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Forums</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the CSS styling for the a tag is as follows:

```
#mainmenu li a {
    color: #fdb813;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding:12px 25px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #ccc;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#mainmenu li a:hover{
    color: #000;
    background: url(images/menuhover.png) repeat;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 4px #777;
}
```

i want to do the transition between the normal state and the hover state with a fadeIn and fadeOut.. i'm no jQuery expert so i've tried hacking into code but i always end up with a disappearing menu !

-EDIT-

well to be me clear, this is how i want the transition to be like:

Hover-in: the background-image & text-color should gradually appear. while the original text remains as is (it shouldnt disappear at the start of the transition)

hover-out: the bg-img and text should gradually disappear (showing the original state)

-EDIT 2-

so far i've managed to make the fadeIn transition, using the following piece.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#mainmenu li a').hover(
                function () {
                    $(this).css('opacity',0.1).animate({opacity: 1},250);
                }, //this is called on hover in
                function () {
                    $(this).addClass('hovered');
                    $(this).fadeOut(function(){
                        $(this).removeClass('hovered').fadeIn(250);
                    });
                } //this is called on hover out
            );
       }); 
</script>
```

however the transition on fadeOut is acting somewhat weird.
i'm open to any suggestions.
Note: the class 'hovered' is a class matching the a:hover CSS selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am assuming you want to perform some animation on mouse hover. 
below is the simple code that you can go for.

1. bind the hover event to each of your anchors which you can do as below

   ```
   $('#mainmenu').find('a').hover(function(){

      //comes here upon hover
   });
   ```
2. perform fadeIn or fadeOut or animate. below is the super simple code doing so.

   ```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mainmenu').find('a').hover(
          function(){
               $(this).animate({opacity: 0.25}, 200, function() { }); 
              } ///gets called when hover in
         ,
          function(){
                $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 200, function() {}); 

           }//gets called when hover out
        );
        }); 
     </script>
   ```

so basically you are performing an animate upon hover on an anchor and then removing the effects produced upon hover out. this is very simply case, dedicated to provide you an idea.

Since you want to animate your background image, you cannot do it through jquery animate method, but through a simple logic. try below script:

```
  <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
             $('#mainmenu').find('a').hover(
             function(){
               $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
                        $(this).css({'background-image': 'url(images/hovermenu.png)'})
                        .animate({opacity: 1});
                        }); 
             } ///gets called when hover in
              ,
             function(){
               $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function() {
                            $(this).css({'background-image': 'url()'})
                        .animate({opacity: 1});
                        }); 
             });
             }); 
          </script>
```

so now what you are doing is,

upon hover-in: you animate opacity of your anchor to 0, assign background-image to it and then animate its opacity back to 1

upon hover-out: you animate opacity of your anchor to 0, remove its background - image and then animate its opacity back to 0

it is close to what you wanted.
see, what you wanted was to make your text static and produce effect on its background-image, which is not possible for your current menu structure.

you will have to separate your text and background-image i.e animate background-image of anyother element kept beneath the anchor.

again m giving you an idea.

Comment: i'm not getting the desired effect, it first shows the hover state with 100% opacity and then fades out to 25% when hovering in.

and when hovering out, the background img abruptly disappears without fading, while the text fades out, and the original text fades back in

Comment: This only alters the opacity of the element, not the CSS that TS provided.

Comment: see @MostafaWasat, i tried to give you an idea, how you can produce animation. As opacity is one of the CSS properties, you can inject anyother css property as well into the animate method. infact, combination of ur css and jquery wud produce desired affect for you. There are more than one ways to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css transitions and jQuery only as a fallback. Here are some links to help:

- http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/10/17/animating-colors-using-css3-transitions-with-jquery-fallback/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_transitions
- http://oli.jp/2010/css-animatable-properties/

Comment: well, I've read both articles, and i must admit its quite a neat approach for doing trasitions :).
However, CSS3 transitions doesn't support background-image transitions yet. i just want the the hover state to fadeIn while appearing, nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
The Js code is below :

$("a").hover(function(){

        $(this).fadeOut(500);
        $(this).fadeIn(500);

    },function(){});
```

first function is called on hoverin and second on hoverout.

You need to include one jquery-latest:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

And you can see effect here : `http://jsfiddle.net/WrspV/`